# Managing EC2 instances via Serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework

How do you use the Serverless framework to manage EC2 instances that Lamdas interact with?

Is there something built into the platform, or do you have to manually create cloud formation instances, like:

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
```

?
          ImageId: 'foobar'